# Spring Batch JPA inheritance

Tags: inheritance, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I try to fix some issue with no success : so i come to you to get some clue in order to help me. I cannot save and read properly data within spring batch datasource and it's include some polymorphism..

Here is the context

**From the model side**

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractBaseDocument implements Serializable {
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTableA")
public class InscriptionDocument extends AbstractBaseDocument {
   // some attributes
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTableB")
public class SaillieDocument extends AbstractBaseDocument {
   // some attributes
}
```

**From the service side**

```
public interface AbstractBaseService<T extends AbstractBaseDocument, ID extends Serializable> {
    public abstract T saveAndFlush(T entity);
}

@Service
public abstract class AbstractBaseServiceImpl<T extends AbstractBaseDocument, ID extends Serializable>
        implements AbstractBaseService<T, ID> {

    private AbstractBaseRepository<T, ID> abstractBaseRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AbstractBaseServiceImpl(AbstractBaseRepository<T, ID> abstractBaseRepository) {
        this.abstractBaseRepository = abstractBaseRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public T saveAndFlush(T entity) {
        return (T) abstractBaseRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
    }
}

public interface SaillieDocumentService extends AbstractBaseService<SaillieDocument, Serializable> {
}

@Service("saillieDocumentService")
public class SaillieDocumentServiceImpl extends AbstractBaseServiceImpl<SaillieDocument, Serializable>
        implements SaillieDocumentService {

    private SaillieDocumentRepository myDomainRepository;

    public SaillieDocumentServiceImpl(SaillieDocumentRepository myDomainRepository) {
        super(myDomainRepository);
    }

}

public interface InscriptionDocumentService extends AbstractBaseService<InscriptionDocument, Serializable> {
}

@Service("inscriptionDocumentService")
public class InscriptionDocumentServiceImpl extends AbstractBaseServiceImpl<InscriptionDocument, Serializable>
        implements InscriptionDocumentService {

    private InscriptionDocumentRepository myDomainRepository;

    public InscriptionDocumentServiceImpl(InscriptionDocumentRepository myDomainRepository) {
        super(myDomainRepository);
    }
}
```

**From the repository side**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface AbstractBaseRepository<T extends AbstractBaseDocument, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
}

public interface InscriptionDocumentRepository extends AbstractBaseRepository<InscriptionDocument, Serializable> {
}

public interface SaillieDocumentRepository extends AbstractBaseRepository<SaillieDocument, Serializable> {
}
```

Finally, i try to save InscriptionDocument as below ...

> ```
> @Autowired
> private InscriptionDocumentService service;
>
> @Override
> public void write(List<? extends AbstractBaseDocument> documents) throws Exception {
>     for (AbstractBaseDocument document : documents) {
>         log.info(">>> Sauvegarde dans la table temporaire {}", document.toString());
>         service.saveAndFlush((InscriptionDocument) document);
>     }
> }
> ```

And my question is : how can I set a generic method to save records without check the Class AbstractDocument (If InscriptionDocument use InscriptionDocumentService Else If SaillieDocument use SaillieDocumentService ...)

Thanks ...

Comment: `I cannot save and read properly data`: can you elaborate please? Do you have an error or stacktrace to share? Or does the job finish without errors but data is not saved to the database? Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you efficiently. WTR to generics, I'm not sure you can have a generic writer as you described. What you can do is create a generic wrapper service that delegates to the right service based on the type of passed object. Then use that wrapper service in your writer.

Comment: About data, in fact I have 2 steps. The first read data from Table A and write data to Table B. The second Step has to read from Table B. But no data to fetch whereas is can see rows on my table with my favorite tools TOAD :)

Comment: Ok will investigate for  generic wrapper ...